# Is life predefined to some extent... what will happen in our life in future?

Tags: krishna

All Vedic astrology proves that, after many predictions of life.....if its true how will be focus on something, which we desire in our life, when its fixed we may not achieve that.

Many times in life we also feel this type of situation when after so much effort in life we have not got the proper results, others got that without effort or some effort.....then what is the role of karma if we will not get the things which are not in our destiny..

Comment: Life is predetermined. By whom? That's the question. You will be surprised at the answer. By YOU! You have decided how your life will go long before you're born. You have the power inside you to undo it. That's the purpose of sadhana. To free your Self (it is called Self for a reason -- it is the real YOU) from the clutches of the Mind. All the best.